# Stock line appeared during page transitions in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, transition

I am developing a mobile webpage using jQueryMobile. I found there is always a line `(at the bottom ~40px)` during page transition especially for `slideup` transition.

for example, when invoking `$.mobile.changePage()` to a new page using `slideup`, a blank white page will displayed with a stock line at middle bottom and then the page gone the new page shown. There's no functional failure just looks odd.

Comment: Screenshot or it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue before and try to search the answers from stackoverflow and github.But I didn't find a very perfect solution.

Finally I try to use some tricks to fix this issue.

About the line :

In default,jquery mobile ui-mobile class or any other classes set the web page min-height as 460px.So I set the min-height as 460+ or heigher.Then the white line would be disappear.

About the page flash or blink :

Normally We would write jquery mobile web app like this :

```
page1: 
<body>
  <div>...All Main Content Here</div>
</body>

page2:
<body>
  <div>...All Main Content Here</div>
</body>
```

But I change it like this :

```
page1:
<body>
  <div id="page1">
    <div>...All Main Content here</div>
  </div>
</body>

page2:
<body>
  <div id="page2" style="display:none">
    <div>...All Main Content here</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And After every page transition call a function :

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#page2").css("display","block"); } , 80 );
```

And you would found that everything is good.